# How to shutdown all dynamic instances in Google App Engine without re-deploying the app?

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, load-testing

We are running multiple load tests every day against one of our GAE apps. We use the following pattern:

1. Start a load test and let it run for a few hours.
2. Look at graphs.
3. Optionally deploy a new version of our app with performance improvements.
4. Go back to 1.

Each load test creates a couple hundred front end instances. We would like to terminate those between individual load tests even when we are not deploying a new version of our app.

**Is there a way to terminate *all* dynamic instances?** Right now we either have to deploy a new version or terminate all instances by hand.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem - I found that disabling the app in Application Settings and then re-enabling it terminated all 88 instances we had running, without any other adverse effects.

Comment: Wouldn't disabling the app stop all incoming traffic temporarily?

Comment: Yes of course, but the question asks how to terminate _all_ dynamic instances.

Even so, it's only down for a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have them all periodically probe the datastore (or memcache) for a kill value?

Comment: Yes, each instance could probe a datastore/memcache kill value. But how could it trigger it's own shutdown based on that?